# Does there exist an established name for the exponential of surprisal (e.g. the reciprocal of probability?)

Tags: terminology, it.information-theory, entropy

There are several different names that I know of for the exponential of the entropy of which "diversity" and "perplexity" are fairly well-established. Tom Leinster has a very interesting post on diversity at [nLab](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2021/07/entropy_and_diversity_is_out.html), noting that "Although diversity is closely related to entropy, the diversity viewpoint really opens up new mathematical questions that you don’t see from a purely information-theoretic standpoint." I have found this to be a useful viewpoint.

If exponential of the entropy is to be viewed as a basic quantity, then on some level, the even deeper basic quantity is the exponential of the surprisal. This is a very simple quantity, being basically just the reciprocal of the probability, but it is interesting to focus on it as the basic unit of "exponential information" and derive various diversity indices from it as various kinds of weighted mean. This is similar to how the Shannon entropy is a weighted mean of the Shannon information (and the Rényi entropy has a similar interpretation).

My question is just: **does this have an established name in the literature**? Basically, it transforms probabilities into a representation of having a "1-in-x" chance of occurring. This is a very natural, basic idea, but it is somewhat awkward to have to write "exponential of surprisal" or "reciprocal of probability" every time. Is there a name for this?

Comment: various names for the reciprocal of probability have been used in different contexts: _rarity, odds, sampling weight, thermodynamic probability,_ see the discussion at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/242999/338593

Comment: Are you asking about the *reciprocal of probability*, the *exponential of the reciprocal of probability*, the *exponential of entropy*, or something else? (And what do you mean by "e.g."?)

Comment: As the title says: I am asking about the "reciprocal of probability," which is the same as the "exponential of surprisal."

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks, had not seen "rarity" before. Somewhat surprised to see "European odds" for this.